# Dynamically Generated Datatable for Google's Annotated Time Line

Tags: php, asp.net, sql, datatable, google-visualization

I want to use [Google's Annotated Time Line Visualization](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/annotatedtimeline.html). It is very easy to make this work by manually adding the lines for column & row data. This is all done through attributes of google.visualization.DataTable().  I would like to update this data table dynamically, but I do not know how. The data is on a server running MS SQL Server 2005.

I found a [post](http://groups.google.com/group/google-visualization-api/browse_thread/thread/4dc84221fbd3ade5/d57109c9b45fd741?lnk=raot&pli=1) to accomplish this with PHP and MySQL, but I do not know how to translate this to VB .NET or C# (either is fine).

Does anyone know how to make this use MS SQL Server data in .NET or of a better way to have the code dynamically generated so new data does not have to have the lines manually added every day?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is an old post but take a look at http://www.panterlo.com/2010/10/17/google-visualization-api-gets-easy-with-net-mvc/ which points out that I released out a class library available at github (GPL v3) that you can use for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the post you mentioned to help you write this code in PHP but use PHP's ODBC functions (https://www.php.net/odbc) to access the data in MSSQL Server instead of the examples shown in accessing a MySQL database.

```
$connectionstring = odbc_connect($db, $user, $pass) or die("Connection Failed");
$query = "...";
$result = odbc_do($connectionstring, $query) or die("Query Failed");
```

Sorry that doesn't help you with .NET or C#.